Changing toolbar icons in QSS for QGIS
I'm trying to change the icons in standard toolbars in qgis. I have a custom theme that i load via the pluging qss loader.
In the file i can chnge just about everything in the ui, but i can't find teh syntax for the qgis ui. I need that to script the right names of the buttons. In the interface customizer i can find the button name, but not the toolbar name.
I tried:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
